# Margin left not working on iPad portrait mode

Tags: ipad, margin, portrait

My site's left margin is not working on iPad (portrait mode). It's perfectly centered in landscape mode but when I turn it to portrait view my left margin seems set to zero. Can you help me with this one?

my website: www.inclouds.co.uk/test
I am using [ipadpeek](http://ipadpeek.com/) to view my site on ipad:

for my css code:

```
#container {

    width: 990px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;


 }
#header {
width: 990px;
height: 220px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: auto;
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the width to 100%. Your forcing it to be wider than the iPad screen in portrait.

Also rather than use that testing site, turn on Developer mode in Safari, connect your device to your computer and open the Web Inspector from Safari's Developer menu.